# remove the capitalized letters from the string

Tags: python

I have to remove the capitalized letters from the string given

When I try to remove the capital letters from the given string, the return function exists at the end of the function which I wrote to print the output causes to the last character to get printed. Is there any better way to solve it?

```
def remove_capitals(a):    
    for i in a:    
          if ord(i)>64 and ord(i)<91:   
               pass  
          else:  
               print(i,end='')  
     return i

print(remove_capitals("A1H5J3ETD"))
```

expected : 153
actual : 153D

Comment: You are returning the last letter, and then you pass the result of the function to the print function, that prints the last letter in this case "D".

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. But how to overcome that without removing the print function outside of the remove_capitals() function?

Comment: Why are you returning `i`? And why are you printing the value returned from the function call?

Comment: If I didn't use return None gets printed. I don't want None printed too. The question was to write a function where they have given the print function below the remove_capitals() function. So I thought I could do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print inside and print the return - you return the last `i` without test .. which is the last letter of your input.

Modifications:

- Instead of checking ordinals and magic numbers, use built in fuction [isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) to decide.
- do not use `pass` - simply do only something if it is ok to do so
- collect all parts into a list and [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them back into a string

Fix:

```
def remove_capitals(a):    
    non_upper = []
    for i in a:    
        if not i.isupper():  
            non_upper.append(i)

    return ''.join(non_upper)


print(remove_capitals("A1H5J3ETD"))
```

Output:

```
153
```

---

You can also append to strings - but strings are immutable so it destroyes the old one and creates a new longer version - which is wasteful:

```
def remove_capitals(a):    
    non_upper = "" 
    for i in a:    
        if not i.isupper():  
            non_upper += i

    return non_upper
```

The only benefit this has, is that it does not use lists - it is slower and more memory intensive.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn python, so is there any other basic way. I haven't even started with the List data structures.

Comment: you can add to strings as well - but it destroyed the old string and creates a new (longer) one - wich is wasteful. Start with `non_upper=""` and use `non_upper = non_upper + i` instead of the list append - this here is better / faster though´.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension

```
def remove_capitals(a):
    return ''.join([x for x in a if ord(x)<64 or ord(x)>91]))
```

Comment: Just to note you can use chained comparisons here (which reads better imho and avoids calling `ord()` twice), eg: `[x for x in a if not (64 <= ord(x) <= 91)]` - but there is always `.isupper()` available which makes it far more explicit rather than dealing with character ordinals... (plus isn't restricted to just ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

The last unwanted character is returned because of the return i statement at the end of your function. If you just want to print out the non-capitalised letters putting return None and just calling the function (not doing print(remove_capitals("A1H5J3ETD")) : remove_capitals("A1H5J3ETD") should do the trick.